# How is the file offset advanced by fstream::read?

Tags: c++

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>


int main(int argc, char * argv [])
{
    std::ifstream f{ "test.syp" };
    std::cout << f.tellg() << '\n';
    char buffer[4];
    f.read(buffer, 4);
    std::cout << f.gcount() << '\n';
    std::cout << f.tellg() << '\n';
}
```

When I execute the above code, I get the following output:

```
0
4
20
```

If I change `ifstream` to `fstream`, I get the same thing except that the last number is 21.

I would expect the last number to be 4 in both instances. Why isn't it?

**Edit:** I get the expected result if I open the file with `std::ios::binary`; it must be a quirk of text-mode

Comment: FWIW, I get the output `0 4 4`. I am using g++ 4.8.2.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: Perhaps this is a bug in Visual Studio 2013.  Let me try on OS X with clang... wut? I get -1 0 -1.  Maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Should the curly braces on line 7 - { "test.syp" } - be instead parentheses?

Comment: The curly braces are the C++11 style initialization. It shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: @Mike: `-1 0 -1` hints that `f` wasn't successfully opened for read - perhaps you don't have a readable `test.syp` in your working directory?

Answer (score 0):

`f.gcount` returns the number of characters read by the last unformatted input operation (in this case, `f.read()`).

`f.tellg()` returns an input position indicator; that's an opaque value that has meaning to `seekg()`, but its numeric value isn't meaningful to user programs.